# Prove Newton's iteration will diverge for these functions, no matter what real starting point is selected. $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $g(x)=7x^4+3x^2+\pi$.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

Prove Newton's iteration will diverge for these functions, no matter what real starting point is selected.

$f(x)=x^2+1$ and $g(x)=7x^4+3x^2+\pi$.

We know that $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so there does not exist a real solution to these polynomials and Newton's Method doesn't apply. Is this basically what the proof of this is or do I need to do it a different way? I don't see how to do this any other way. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try obtaining the recurrence relations formed from Newton's method, then see that the sequences diverge. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence for Newton iteration is
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
If $x_n$ converges to some limit $L$, taking limits in both sides of this equation you have
$$L = L - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
In other words, 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = 0 \tag 1$$
If $f'(L) \neq 0$, then you have
$$ \frac{f(L)}{f'(L)} = 0$$
In other words $f(L) = 0$. Since both of your functions have no zeroes, this case won't happen.

So you have $f'(L) = 0$. What remains is to show $(1)$ is impossible in this situation. But now $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(L)$, while $f'(x_n)$ converges to zero. Since in both cases $f(x)$ never vanishes, you have $f(L) \neq 0$ and the ratio $\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ diverges as $n$ goes to infinity. Hence $(1)$ doesn't occur.

The same argument shows that Newton iteration diverges whenever the function is nonvanishing.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to point out that if for some function there are no roots, then Newton's method for that function will obviously not converge. However, both $f$ and $g$ have complex roots, so Newton's method will probably converge for both of them to some of their complex roots. As a result, you should add that the question is about **real** limits only of the Newton's method.

It seems to me that you are asked to examine the method itself for the functions given. That is, for $f(x)=x^2+1$, for example, you are asked to show that however you choose the initial point $x_0$, if you define

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

then necessarily the sequence $x_n$ will not converge. Indeed, assume $x_0\neq 0$. Since
$f'(x)=2x$, you will have, for $n\geq 0$:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2+1}{2x_n}=\frac{x_n^2-1}{2x_n}$$

If the limit $\lim_n x_n=L$ exists and is different from zero, then passing to the limit on both sides of the Newton's method equation you get:

$$L=\frac{L^2-1}{2L}$$

whence $L^2=-1$, so $L$ is not real. If $L=0$, then the right hand side of the equation, namely $\frac{x_n^2-1}{2x_n}$ tends to $-\infty$, contradicting the fact that the left hand side tends to zero. Finally, if you start with $x_0=0$, then already $x_1$ is undefined.

A similar argument may be used for the second function as well.

Answer (score 1):

In justifying a failure to converge, we could use the condition $$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = 0.$$  But consider $$f(x) = (x-1)^{1/3}.$$  This function obviously has the root $x = 1$.  And the above criterion applied to this choice easily gives $$3(x-1) = 0,$$ or $x = 1$.  Yet the iteration of $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ for any choice $x_0 \ne 1$ is in fact divergent.  To see this, we note that for this choice of $f$, $$x_{n+1} = x_n - 3(x_n - 1) = -2x_n + 3.$$  While $x = 1$ is a fixed point, it is a **repelling** point.  For if $x_n = 1 + \epsilon$, we get $$x_{n+1} = -2(1+\epsilon) + 3 = 1 - 2\epsilon,$$ and $$x_{n+2} = -2(1-2\epsilon)+3 = 1+4\epsilon.$$  Thus if $\epsilon \ne 0$ represents an initial error term, the absolute error from $1$ *doubles* with each iteration.

When we look at Newton's method for complex-valued functions, the dynamics are even more rich; we can get limit cycles, chaos, etc.  While it may be *sufficient* to show that the first condition $f/f' = 0$ is not satisfied, it is not a *necessary* criterion to demonstrate a failure of the sequence to converge.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's method "applies" in the following sense: if $f$ is a real-valued differentiable function on the real line, and $x_0$ is any real starting point, then we can define the sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$ by 
$x_{n+1} = x_n - f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$ (unless we are unlucky enough to reach a point where $f'(x_n) = 0$, in which case we have to stop).

Now suppose
the sequence converges: that means we don't stop, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$ exists as a real number.  Suppose further that $f'$ is a continuous function (which is certainly the case in your examples).  Then as $n \to \infty$ we have 
$f(x_n) \to f(L)$ and $f'(x_n) \to f'(L)$.   But also $f(x_n)  = f'(x_n) (x_{n+1} - x_n) \to 0$.  Thus we must have $f(L) = 0$.

To put it another way (the contrapositive): if $f(x) = 0$ has no real solution,  such an $L$ can't exist, i.e. the sequence must either stop or diverge.

The question is not **quite** correct in that it does not take into account the possibility of the sequence stopping (which is not normally included in the meaning of "diverge").  That happens if you take $x_0 = 0$ in either of your examples.

Comment: The sequence  only stops at a zero of the function, which doesn't happen in either case here.

Comment: @Zarrax By "stop" I mean that further terms are not defined.  How would you describe what the sequence does when $x_0 = 0$?

Comment: Ok... though one could just consider that as another case of the series not converging. Which, as you say, is not the same as diverging.